# How to create a pivot table on pandas DATE column and calculate time difference?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following Dataframe,

```
D_DATE       BIN Number   Disposition    Unit Assigned        
2018-01-04    10005      SWO Issued      PLUMBING DIVISION     
2016-06-23    10005      SWO Issued      SCAFFOLD UNIT         
2016-06-23    10005      SWO Rescinded   SCAFFOLD UNIT         
2018-01-17    10005      SWO Rescinded   PLUMBING DIVISION  
2019-01-04    10006      SWO Rescinded   BEST SQUAD 
2018-12-21    10006      SWO Issued      BEST SQUAD 
2020-02-10    10006      SWO Issued      BEST SQUAD
2020-02-25    10006      SWO Rescinded   BEST SQUAD

df = pd.DataFrame({'D_DATE':['2018-01-04','2016-06-23','2016-06-23','2018-01-17','2019-01-04','2018-12-21','2020-02-10','2020-02-25'],
                    'BIN Number': ['10005', '10005', '10005', '10005', '10006','10006','10006','10006] ,
                   'Disposition': ['SWO Issued', 'SWO Issued', 'SWO Rescinded', 'SWO Rescinded','SWO Rescinded','SWO Issued','SWO Issued','SWO Rescinded'] ,
                   'Unit Assigned': ['PLUMBING DIVISION', 'SCAFFOLD UNIT', 'SCAFFOLD UNIT', 'PLUMBING DIVISION','BEST SQUAD','BEST SQUAD','BEST SQUAD','BEST SQUAD']})
```

I want to create a pivot table if possible, so that I have two columns for the date, one column for the issue data and another for rescinded date, but in the pivot I need to maintain the unit, so I should end up with three columns:

Unit, Issue Date, Rescinded Date

Then next I want to calculate time difference between Issue Date and Rescinded date.

Output:

```
Unit Assigned      SWO Issued     SWO Rescinded    Time Difference
PLUMBING DIVISION  2018-01-04     2018-01-17        13 days
SCAFFOLD UNIT      2016-06-23     2016-06-23        0 days
BEST SQUAD         2018-12-21     2019-01-04        14 days
BEST SQUAD         2020-02-10     2020-02-25        15 days
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is `pivot/pivot_table`:

```
# convert to datetime if not already is
df['D_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['D_DATE'])

(df.assign(idx=df.groupby(['BIN Number', 'Disposition','Unit Assigned']).cumcount())
   .pivot_table(index=['idx','BIN Number', 'Unit Assigned'], 
                columns='Disposition', 
                values='D_DATE',
                aggfunc='first')
   .reset_index()
   .assign(Time_Different=lambda x: x['SWO Rescinded'] - x['SWO Issued'])
   .drop('idx',axis=1)

)
```

Output:

```
Disposition     BIN Number  Unit Assigned       SWO Issued  SWO Rescinded   Time_Different
0               10005       PLUMBING DIVISION   2018-01-04  2018-01-17      13 days 
1               10005       SCAFFOLD UNIT       2016-06-23  2016-06-23      0 days
2               10006       BEST SQUAD          2018-12-21  2019-01-04      14 days
3               10006       BEST SQUAD          2020-02-10  2020-02-25      15 days
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks it works but there is a slight problem. For example, if I have the same unit Issue & Rescind SWO on same BIN Number on different time it can't calculate that. If plumbing unit issues another SWO on BIN 10005 then that doesn't show up. It only shows for the first one.

Comment: The post is updated now. please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: nailed it!! Great. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.